# AngularJS application communcation with PHP file on XAMP Localhost

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, cors

I've had this problem for over a day now and I'm at my wits end regarding it! Firstly, I've never worked with `AngularJS` before and whilst I can see the benefits there is a huge learning curve. I'm trying to send a request from my `Angular` application out to a `php` file using `$httpd.post()` but every time I do it I get the below error in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/angular-service/index.php. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Let me go into more detail.

Angular Application is running on `Gulp server` and the `PHP` file is hosted on `XAMP localhost`. Gulp is running port 8080 and XAMP on port 80.

I attempted to configure XAMP to enable CORS Headers by going to the `httpd.conf` file and adding the following at the very bottom:

```
<Directory />
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, POST"
</Directory>
```

This unfortunately didn't make any impact.

The block of code in my `angular` application which is making the request is here:

```
 $scope.getSomething = function () {       
     $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/angular-service/index.php",
          data: "",
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).
        success(function(response) {
            if(response==1){
               console.log(response);
            }
        }).
        error(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

The `PHP` file is here:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
echo "I'm a PHP File";
```

Can anyone please point me into the right direction as to what I need to do to resolve this. It's incredibly frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add the request methods in your PHP file also.
Here is an example:

```
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain");

   /* Allowed request method */
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT");

   /* Allowed custom header */
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

   /* Age set to 1 day to improve speed caching */
   header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");

   /* Options request exits before the page is completely loaded */ 
   if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'options') 
   {
      exit();
   }

   /* Response data */ 
   $arr = array("user_name" => "tizen", "phone_number" => "12312334234");   

   /* Response data returned in JSON format */
   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

More info about the CORS protocol is found [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol)

Comment: Still getting the same result Matheno

Comment: I added an URL with more info about the CORS protocol. I suggest you to read that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

This helped when I was getting same issue with `PHP` and `Angularjs`..